# Is it permissible to fast on aidiladha?

Tags: halal-haram, sawm, eid-ul-adha

Is there a hadith from Rasulullah s.a.w or verse in the Quran that clarifies this problem? If possible I would like to know the elaboration from scholars.

edit, even if the person wants to compensate for the fast in previous ramadan, is it not permissible?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no fasting on one of the two 'auds is haram.

According to this [Fatwa](http://islamqa.info/en/21049) it is even neither permissible to fast nor the fasting will be valid neither for 'id al-adha عيد الأضحى nor for the 3 days after it (ayaam at-Tashreeq أيام التشريق) and if one fasts these days he should repeat it afterwards. If he was fasting before for compensation he should interrupt his fasting until those days are passed!

As we have the following ahadith:

> - ['A'isha](http://sunnah.com/muslim/13/182) (Allah be pleased with her) said that the Prophet (ﷺ) forbade to observe fast on two days-the day of Fitr and the day of
>     Adha.
>
>   [Sahih [Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/13/180) and other Versions in Sahih al-Bukhari etc.]
> - Nubaisha al-Hudhali reported Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) as saying: The days of Tashriq are the days of eating and drinking.
>
> [Sahih Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/13/183)

on this matter.

And Allah knows best!